Show New Products on Specific Category
I have created a category I want to show only those products that are created in the last 30 days automatically

Do you need to get a product collection for a specific category?

yes I want to get for a specific category
I also implement some solution

i will share a product collection for a specific category.
app/code/Vendor/ProductCollection/Block/RecentProducts.php
<?PHP

namespace Vendor\ProductCollection\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class RecentProducts extends Template
{
   protected $productCollectionFactory;
  const CATEGORY_ID = 10; // Replace with your specific category ID

public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

public function getRecentProducts()
{
    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-30 days'));
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $fromDate])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $toDate])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', ['neq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE])
        ->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => self::CATEGORY_ID]); // Filtering by specific category ID

    return $collection;
}
}

app/code/Vendor/ProductCollection/view/frontend/templates/recent_products.phtml
<?PHP
$products = $block->getRecentProducts();
if ($products->getSize()): ?>
<h2>Recently Added Products in This Category</h2>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <li><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
 <?php else: ?>
    <p>No recent products found in this category.</p>
  <?php endif; ?>

app/code/Vendor/ProductCollection/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\ProductCollection\Block\RecentProducts" name="recent.products" template="Vendor_ProductCollection::recent_products.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>

apply below command and check it.
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_ProductCollection
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f
php bin/magento cache:clean

if strtotime('-30 days') not working then you can change your logic as magento standard
$fromDate = (new \DateTime())->modify('-30 days')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
or
$today = new DateTime();
$fromDate = $today->modify('-30 days');


In the above code, in the frontend how can it specify the specific category will show only the recently added products in the only on that category
